# Git-receive-pack error over SSH pushing

Tags: git, ssh, ftp

I am trying to push my local git repository to a ssh server, where I have neither root access nor the git command line installed.

Since I have seen that git also supports ftp pushing i have thought that when a push is performed the remote git command line is not used because after all all we need is just to upload the .git folder.

So I thought that since there is no root privileges nor remote git command line execution needed my SSH server would then do the job. I just need the server for hosting. All the commiting is done locally and then pushed.

However when I try to push over SSH my repository I get the following error:

> *** SSH forbidden git-receive-pack path 'MYPATH'

So I'd like to know what may cause this error.
Or how to do the pushing through ftp
I tried git push ftp://user@domain.com/path but it did not work too

> Cannot push refs to `ftp://user@domain.com/path`